# Securing a new office 365 deployment

Tags: microsoft-office-365, microsoft-office, office365

I'd like to know if somebody here might be able to point me in the right direction.

Rolling out a new O365 deployment and we would like to secure it.
What I mean is that unless the user is logged into our internal network, they won't be able to transfer or move data off of the network (within reason). I understand this may sound vague, but primary goal is to configure so that users cannot log into the O365 web portal unless logged onto our internal network, and can't copy files to onedrive to access from home, etc.

I work in a law firm and there are very strict guidelines about how data is to be handled and accessed.

Basically lock it down as much as possible, with the exception of a few admin users. I also understand that people can always email files to themselves, but we can only do what we can do.

Thank you for any insights anyone might be able to provide.

Comment: At the very least you're probably looking at conditional access policies. This will require Azure AD Premium 1 licenses. You'll also want to look at DLP in the Security and Compliance center.

Comment: Thank you very much for that